Why is some pachysandra dying?
I planted some cuttings last year and they all did well until this year. While I planted many more cuttings this year, some of the established plants are wilting, developing brown leaves, and dying.
The soil is consistently moist and the entire bed is almost is in full shade, with some spotted morning light.





They're not thirsty?

@YosefBaskin I don't think so. I test with my finger every few days and over half of them are doing well. Any danger in over watering?
